# How To Count Unique Values Based On Another Column In Excel

Tags: excel-formula, sumproduct

[image]

I am trying to calculate the number of unique values in A column based on the corresponding values in column B. I should get 3 unique values corresponding to 10 and 1 corresponding to 15.

What I have tried so far?

Let's say 10 is in the cell D2

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$5=D2))/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,$A$2:$A$5&"",$B$2:$B$5,$B$2:$B$5&""))
```

Then using ctrl+shift+enter I've made the formula into array, but I get 0. It is wrong.

Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't `($A$2:$A$5=D2)` be `($B$2:$B$5=D2)`?

Comment: `=COUNTA(FILTER(A$2:A$5;B$2:B$5=B2))` would give the result you like, I guess. This required office 365 though.

Comment: It worked out ($A$2:$A$5=D2) changing with ($B$2:$B$5=D2)

Comment: The full formula
=SUMPRODUCT((($B$2:$B$5=D2))/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,$A$2:$A$5&"",$B$2:$B$5,$B$5:$B$5&""))
ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: Would anyone give a try explaining how the formula works?